# Cross Join between tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have 2 tables having columns like this:

```
Table 1 : Name, Date and Credits Gain
Table 2 : Name , Date and Credits lost
```

I need to do a cross join with these 2 tables to get data like below:

```
Name, Date, Credits Gain, Credits lost
```

Could anyone please help?

Comment: do u want in SQL or Oracle ?

Comment: @nad I need In Oracle

Comment: how many columns do u have in Table 2 ?

Comment: Do you know what a cross join is? Usually it's not something you want.

Comment: could you please help me.im new to oracle

Comment: @Mounika: your requirement doesn't matches with the feature of `CROSS JOIN`. You need to first learn the `JOINS` and which joins will apply at which places. For more info [https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/joins.php#:~:text=Oracle%20JOINS%20are%20used%20to,or%20sometimes%20called%20LEFT%20JOIN)]

Comment: Which Name and Date you like to get? They exist in both tables, thus at CROSS join they will appear twice in the result. Most likely that is not what you actually like to get.

Comment: @Nad: Oracle does use SQL as its query language. In fact it was the first commercial relational database to use SQL

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks as if you don't actually want cross join (Cartesian product; that doesn't make much sense), but inner (or perhaps outer?) join.

Something like this:

```
SELECT a.name,
       a.date_column,
       a.credits_gain,
       b.credits_lost
  FROM table1 a
       JOIN table2b
          ON     a.name = b.name
             AND a.date_column = b.date_column
```